# Raspbian + GPG + IDEA/RSA (old PGP support)

Tags: raspbian

I want to use GPG on Raspberry but need support for older keys (RSA/IDEA/CAST) from PGP 2.6. I read for additional modules for GPG which support these algorithms like this:

https://arthurdejong.org/gnupg-idea/

But not sure whether this will work on Raspbian/ARM because of incompatible or missing libraries or other reason.

Answer (score 1):

The linked website provides a source package. The instructions will build the source package.

Closer examination of the source package reveals **that the building process will try to download a file called idea.c.gz** and compile it.

This will also work on the Pi, since the code (idea.c) is written in **portable C** without assembler.

Comment: IDEA is one of the missing algorithms in GPG. It is not the only difference with PGP 2.x. Your answer sounds like a supposition not a good knowledge of PGP/GPG.